# How to export data as a XES file in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

I am working on a application that allows users upload and edit CSV files containing process activity logs. 
I am not storing the data in the database. 
So far the user can download the data as a new .csv file.

Now I want to convert that data into a XES file (this a special XML format used mainly for process mining in tools such as ProM framework).

I couldn't find any hint on how to do that. 
I wonder if there's a rails gem or something.

Thanks in advance

ps.: [here](https://github.com/llevvi/pesquisa-iff) is the project code.

Answer (score 0):

A simple method would be imported in Disco and by using this tool, exported in XES format ( I always use this method). 
If you don't access to Disco another solution would be used ProM software. There is a plugin for this platform for converting CSV file to XES format ( developed by F. Mannhardt).